# Add suburb to Google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to add a suburb to my Google Map as below. I can see you need to add the Longitude and latitude to the map but how do you get this? I have the suburb only. How can I show this in the map?

Here is my sample code. Appreciate any help on this one.

```js
 // This example creates circles on the map, representing populations in North
      // America.

      // First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
      var citymap = {
        chicago: {
          center: {lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629},
          population: 2714856
        },
        newyork: {
          center: {lat: 40.714, lng: -74.005},
          population: 8405837
        },
        losangeles: {
          center: {lat: 34.052, lng: -118.243},
          population: 3857799
        },
        vancouver: {
          center: {lat: 49.25, lng: -123.1},
          population: 603502
        }
      };

      function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: 37.090, lng: -95.712},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });

        // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
        // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
        for (var city in citymap) {
          // Add the circle for this city to the map.
          var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: citymap[city].center,
            radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
          });
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    
    
     <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAgtbeVVsty_xvo1ntINd-G1uA_5IBw0pA&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What "suburb" are you trying to add to the map?  You need the geographic coordinates of the boundary of that suburb.  Then create a google.maps.Polygon from them and add it to the map.

Answer (score 0):

add

`visible: true`

to your circle object